# SQL Server : master database cleanup

Tags: sql-server

My users have been adding tables - mostly blank - and stored procedures to the master database. They have too many rights and the time-honoured principal is: "if the users can, they will."

I have to restrict their rights. Then I want to clean up.

What harm do hundreds of empty objects on the master database do?

Do they affect performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't have thought that there was any processor / memory performance implications per se; unless the stored procedures have nasties and are run regularly.

The biggest performance problems will be developer / DBA cycles trying to find the right table or stored procedure, and understanding what's going on, and who will be affected by changing something. A table may be empty, but a connected application may fail if it goes missing, for example.

Good luck!